# how to select elements from the current node by selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to select contact information by selenium on the website below:

http://buyersguide.recyclingtoday.com/search.

For matching the right information one by one, I want to select the rows first, and then select information from the rows. The simple code as below,  my question now is how to select the information from each row. For example, company name, email.

**Code:**

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://buyersguide.recyclingtoday.com/search')
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="Body_tbl"]/tbody/tr')
for row in rows:
    email = row.find_element_by_xpath('//*/tr/td[3]/a').text
    company=row.find_element_by_xpath('//*/tr/td[1]').text
```

Run the code as answers below, but I still face problem?

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://buyersguide.recyclingtoday.com/search')

rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="Body_tbl"]/tbody/tr')
records = [] 
for row in rows:
     company=row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]').text
     address = row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text
     contact= row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[3]//a').text
     number= row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]').text
     records.append((company,address,contact,number))


df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['company','number','address', 'contact'])
```

No content selected

Comment: are telling that you want the data from all the pages?

Comment: yes, i need the whole data from all the pages,but the code i write seems no work,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get details like,

*You have to locate number of Row available in the table without Table Header,*

This is Example as according to your HTML.

**Example using Python:**

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@style='font-weight:bold;']//parent::tr")
for row in rows:
     company=row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]').text
     address = row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text
     contact= row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[3]//a').text
     number= row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]').text
```

**Example using Java:**

```
List<WebElement> findData = driver.findElements("//td[@style='font-weight:bold;']//parent::tr");
        for (WebElement webElement : findData) {
            String getValueofCompany = webElement.findElement(By.xpath("./td[1]")).getText();
            String getValueofAddress = webElement.findElement(By.xpath("./td[2]")).getText();
            String getValueofContact = webElement.findElement(By.xpath("./td[3]//a")).getText();
            String getValueofPhoneNumber = webElement.findElement(By.xpath("./td[5]")).getText();           
        }
```

Comment: Email id text will not work because it does not contains email directly in text in many cases so we require value of href attribute

e.g. '//tbody//tr[4]//td[3]/a'

Comment: @Amit Yes, I missed <a> for Emails. I have updated solution.

Comment: also we get an error as below File "<ipython-input-62-94e1b71ee87b>", line 10
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@style='font-weight:bold;']//parent::tr')
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Updated with Double " "  ("//td[@style='font-weight:bold;']//parent::tr")

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
for row in rows:
    email = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[3]/a').text
    company = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[1]').text
```

Comment: i print email or company to check,but return a name error can you tell me why, NameError: name 'company' is not defined

Comment: print("{} {}".format(email, company))
this works for me in the for loop, please share your code if you still face issue..

Comment: ok, i share full code for reference, this is still have problem, please try to run

Comment: As @Amit Jain pointed out, if you check the website, the first and last two rows do not have any data. So you need to run this `rows=rows[2:-2]` before going over your for loop. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The data which you want starts from

`tr[3]//td[1]` - contains company Name as text

`tr[3]//td[3]` - contains email but in href attribute

So looping over `tr` starts from index 3 to `rows` WebElement length

```
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="Body_tbl"]/tbody/tr')
    for index, element in enumerate(rows,start=2):
        companyName = rows.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[" + index + "]//td[1]")
    if companyName is not None:
        companyName.getText();
    companyEmail = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[" + index + "]//td[3]/a")
    if companyEmail is not None:
        companyEmail.get_attribute("href"); // this will give exact if email is there
```

Note -  I was not able to test code, please take care of boundary conditions. Thanks